# Saving ImageView content in memory? What is the best approach?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've been looking for this answer online all morning long and I didn't find exactly what I needed. I want the user to add an image from his library and it would appear on the screen. I've managed to write the code that allows me to do that. However, I want that image to be saved. By that, I mean that I want the image selected to still appear after the user closes the app and reopens it. How can I do that?
Any help would be really appreciated :)
I've attached my code:

```
import UIKit

class Schedule: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!   
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()    
@IBAction func addImage(sender: AnyObject) {

    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
    imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary        
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)        
}


// User picks image

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = pickedImage                
    }        
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)                
}

// User cancels picking image action

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    imagePicker.delegate = self        
}    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `NSUserDefault`, It will store your image data and you can retrieve it later. Change your `viewDidLoad` like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()        
     imagePicker.delegate = self 
     if let imageData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("image") as? NSData {
         self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
     }
}
```

Now you need to store this imageData in `NSUserDefault` when you select image from `UIImagePicker`

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
         imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
         imageView.image = pickedImage
         let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage)              
         NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "image")
         NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize() 
     }        
     dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)                
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I think I understand what you wrote. I added these to my code. Everything is good except I'm getting an error on the line: let date = UIImagePngRepresentation(image). It says "cannot convert type UIImageView to type UIImage"

Comment: Check my edit. `let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage)`

Comment: Sorry my page wasnt refreshed. But it worked now!! Thank you so much

Comment: @I_like_cocoa just wrote it, then u did it... ;-)